# Assign an array in an array variable in PHP

Tags: php

I want to assign an array as an value of another variable in PHP. First array is

```
<?php 
    $jsonData = array(
       'EndUserIp' => $ipAddress,
       'TokenId' => 'a58c1052-c08f-4f40-9a9c-8841de585a14',
       'AdultCount' => 1,
       'ChildCount' => 0,
       'InfantCount' => 0,
       'DirectFlight' => 1,
       'OneStopFlight' => 0,
       'JourneyType' => 1,
       'Segments'
    );
?>
```

The second array is:

```
<?php
    $segmentVal = array(
       'Origin' => 'DEL', 
       'Destination' => 'CCU',
       'FlightCabinClass' => 2, 
       'PreferredDepartureTime' => '2017-10-13T00:00:00', 
       'PreferredArrivalTime' => '2017-10-13T00:00:00'
    );
?>
```

I want to assign the second array as the value of Segment variable in the first array.

Comment: Note that your `$jsonData` contains `0 => 'Segments'`. The single trailing `'Segments'` there is a value, not a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following way to do array combine.

1)

```
<?php
$segmentVal = array(
      'Origin' => 'DEL',
      'Destination' => 'CCU',
      'FlightCabinClass' => 2,
      'PreferredDepartureTime' => '2017-10-13T00:00:00',
      'PreferredArrivalTime' => '2017-10-13T00:00:00'
   );


  $jsonData = array(
      'EndUserIp' => $ipAddress,
      'TokenId' => 'a58c1052-c08f-4f40-9a9c-8841de585a14',
      'AdultCount' => 1,
      'ChildCount' => 0,
      'InfantCount' => 0,
      'DirectFlight' => 1,
      'OneStopFlight' => 0,
      'JourneyType' => 1,
      'Segments' => $segmentVal
   );
?>
```

2)

```
<?php

    $jsonData = array(
          'EndUserIp' => $ipAddress,
          'TokenId' => 'a58c1052-c08f-4f40-9a9c-8841de585a14',
          'AdultCount' => 1,
          'ChildCount' => 0,
          'InfantCount' => 0,
          'DirectFlight' => 1,
          'OneStopFlight' => 0,
          'JourneyType' => 1,
          'Segments' => array(
               'Origin' => 'DEL',
               'Destination' => 'CCU',
               'FlightCabinClass' => 2,
               'PreferredDepartureTime' => '2017-10-13T00:00:00',
               'PreferredArrivalTime' => '2017-10-13T00:00:00'
            )
       );

    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

try $jsonData['Segments'] = $segmentVal;

Comment: @AnkurBiswas: You should accept as answer if your problem solved

Answer (score -1):

I came up with two possible ways to do so

First one is passing encoding the second array with json as  below

```
$jsonData = array(
    'EndUserIp' => "192.168.0.10",
    'TokenId' => 'a58c1052-c08f-4f40-9a9c-8841de585a14',
    'AdultCount' => 1,
    'ChildCount' => 0,
    'InfantCount' => 0,
    'DirectFlight' => 1,
    'OneStopFlight' => 0,
    'JourneyType' => 1,
    'Segments' => json_encode($segmentVal),
);
```

The second one is similar 
You can serialize the `$segmentVal` as below

```
$jsonData = array(
    'EndUserIp'     => "192.168.0.10",
    'TokenId'       => 'a58c1052-c08f-4f40-9a9c-8841de585a14',
    'AdultCount'    => 1,
    'ChildCount'    => 0,
    'InfantCount'   => 0,
    'DirectFlight'  => 1,
    'OneStopFlight' => 0,
    'JourneyType'   => 1,
    'Segments'      => serialize($segmentVal),
);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.